# How can I get the last 5 row start in each group

Tags: r

```
    finger_index    finger_state    data_source x      y    eventMask  Tap  group
    0                PalmOn         PTP         1155   241      0      0    a
    1                PalmOn         PTP         13     178      0      0    a
    2                FingerOn       PTP         255    671      0      0    a
    3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    0                PalmOn         PTP         1155   241      0      0    a
    1                PalmOn         PTP         13     178      0      0    a
    2                FingerOn       PTP         255    671      0      0    a
    3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    0                PalmOn         PTP         1156   241      0      0    a
    1                PalmOn         PTP         13     178      0      0    a
    2                FingerOn       PTP         255    671      0      0    a
    3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    0                PalmOn         PTP         1161   240      0      0    a
    1                PalmOn         PTP         13     178      0      0    a
    2                FingerOn       PTP         255    671      0      0    a
    3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    0                PalmOn         PTP         1181   234      0      0    a
    1                PalmOn         PTP         13     178      0      0    a
    2                NoObject       PTP         255    671      0      0    a
    3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    0                PalmOn         PTP         1190   231      0      0    a
    1                PalmOn         PTP         12     177      0      0    a
    2                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
    NA               NA             NA          NA     NA       2048   1    b
so on with this pattern
```

Desired output:

```
finger_index    finger_state    data_source x      y    eventMask  Tap  group
        0                PalmOn         PTP         1155   241      0      0    a
        1                PalmOn         PTP         13     178      0      0    a
        2                FingerOn       PTP         255    671      0      0    a
        3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
        4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
        0                PalmOn         PTP         1155   241      0      0    a
        1                PalmOn         PTP         13     178      0      0    a
        2                FingerOn       PTP         255    671      0      0    a
        3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
        4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
        0                PalmOn         PTP         1156   241      0      0    a
        1                PalmOn         PTP         13     178      0      0    a
        2                FingerOn       PTP         255    671      0      0    a
        3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
        4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
        0                PalmOn         PTP         1161   240      0      0    a
        1                PalmOn         PTP         13     178      0      0    a
        2                FingerOn       PTP         255    671      0      0    a
        3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
        4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
        NA               NA             NA          NA     NA       2048   1    b
```

I have this group of data that I generated, finger_index from 0 to 4 are in same set.

```
0                PalmOn         PTP         1155   241      0      0    a
1                PalmOn         PTP         13     178      0      0    a
2                FingerOn       PTP         255    671      0      0    a
3                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
4                NoObject       PTP         0      0        0      0    a
```

I want to choose 5 sets of the rows from tail. I have to ignore the set that does not have "FingerOn"
.
I have few placeholder that is call group b. the reason that I created the group a, b because I want to use this code:

```
  # tapFilter <- DT[, if (group[1] != "a") .SD else tail(.SD, 25), # by = .(group, rleid(group))][, -2]
```

However, I cant use this now, because I have to skip the set that does not have FingerOn in the set.

I think the easier version is using data.table. How can I achieve this task?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell which variable is used to arrange the dataset?

Comment: Hi, In each row I have time_stamp column, but the data too large. I delete the column. I arrange the dataset by time_stamp. I will edit it Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I exactly understand what you want but take a look at this solution. Replace the name of datasets and "time_stamp" variable accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)
df_filtered <- df %>%
  group_by(time_stamp) %>%
  filter(any(finger_state == "FingerOn")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  tail(., n=25)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for unclear explanation. I have few placeholder that is call group b. the reason that I created the group a, b because I want to use this code:
`      # tapFilter <- DT[, if (group[1] != "a") .SD else tail(.SD, 25), 
      #                 by = .(group, rleid(group))][, -2]`
However, I cant use this now, because I have to skip the set that does not have FingerOn in the set. 
Thanks!